# Array type promotion in Julia

Tags: julia, type-promotion

In Julia, I can use `promote` to make various types of objects compatible.  For example:

```
>promote(1, 1.0)
(1.0,1.0)
>typeof(promote(1, 1.0))
(Float64, Float64)
```

However, if I use `promote` on arrays, it doesn't give me what I want:

```
>promote([1], [1.0])
([1],[1.0])
>typeof(promote([1], [1.0]))
(Array{Int64,1},Array{Float64,1})
```

What I want is for the `Int64` array to be converted to a `Float64` array, so I get something like:

```
>promote_array([1], [1.0])
([1.0],[1.0])
>typeof(promote_array([1], [1.0]))
(Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1})
```

Here `promote_array` is a hypothetical function I made up.  I'm looking for a real function that does the same.  Is there a function in Julia that does what `promote_array` does above?

Answer (score 4):

I found the function `Base.promote_eltype`, which I can use to get what I want:

```
function promote_array(arrays...)
  eltype = Base.promote_eltype(arrays...)
  tuple([convert(Array{eltype}, array) for array in arrays]...)
end
```

This `promote_array` function then gives me the output I'm looking for:

```
>promote_array([1], [1.0])
([1.0],[1.0])
>typeof(promote_array([1], [1.0]))
(Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1})
```

The above solves my problem, although the existence of `Base.promote_eltype` suggests there may be an already built solution that I don't know about yet.

Comment: Ah didn't see this. This is essentially same as mine, except using parametric functions to extract the eltype.

Comment: This operation is done for almost all linear algebra functions so you could have a look inside the `linalg` directory. There we promote to a type for which the element type is closed under the arithmetic operations of the algebra computation, e.g. an LU requires rations and a QR requires 2-norms. When the right element type has been calculated you can compute the new array either with `convert(AbstractArray{Float64}, [1 0; 0 1])` or `LinAlg.copy_oftype([1 0;0 1], Float64)` where the last ensures no aliasing, but is only defined in 0.4.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do:

```
function promote_array{S,T}(x::Vector{S},y::Vector{T})
    U = promote_type(S,T)
    convert(Vector{U},x), convert(Vector{U},y)
end
```

I'm not sure what your use case is exactly, but the following pattern is something I see as being fairly commonly required for code that has the tightest typing possible while being general:

```
function foo{S<:Real, T<:Real}(x::Vector{S},y::Vector{T})
    length(x) != length(y) && error("Length mismatch")
    result = zeros(promote_type(S,T), length(x))
    for i in 1:length(x)
        # Do some fancy foo-work here
        result[i] = x[i] + y[i]
    end
    return result
end
```